# Django rest framework list of manytomany relational fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an app that allows for me to upload my artwork and also have a carousel of a subset of those artworks. I want to have a Carousel object that I select images for it.

```
from django.db import models
from artwork.models import Artwork

# Carousel Model references the artworks in a many to many field

class Carousel(models.Model):
    carouseltitle = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    artwork = models.ManyToManyField(Artwork)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Carousel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Carousels'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.carouseltitle
```

In my serializer, very simply creates what I want except for pulling Artwork fields:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Carousel
from artwork.models import Artwork


class CarouselSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Carousel
        fields = ('id', 'carouseltitle', 'artwork')
```

My view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Carousel
from .serializers import CarouselSerializer
from rest_framework import generics

# Create your views here.
class CarouselListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Carousel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarouselSerializer
```

Creates this output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "carouseltitle": "Home",
        "artwork": [
            2,
            4,
            6
        ]
    }
]
```

For the artwork list, I want to list field from the artwork such as the url to the image and the title, not just the PK. For the life of me everything I try gives me errors. Can anyone steer me in the right direcdtion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a ModelSerializer for the artwork, then use that in your `CarouselSerializer`:

```py
class ArtworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Artwork
        fields = artwork_fields_to_show


class CarouselSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artwork = ArtworkSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Carousel
        fields = ('id', 'carouseltitle', 'artwork')
```

You also don't need to declare that ID is a readonly field :)

Comment: I knew it had to be simple. Thank you for the easy to understand explanation.